# How to use toString method when initializing a deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays

I was assigned a project where I have to create a video poker program with a Card class to initialize the deck. I've been trying to do this myself and i came up with

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Cards
{
    private int number, suit;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Cards
     */
    public Cards()
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[12];
        int[] suits = new int[3];
    }
    public int getSuit(int[] suits)
    {
        int randSuit;
        Random gen = new Random();        
        randSuit = suits[gen.nextInt(4)];
        return randSuit;
    }
    public int getNumber(int[] numbers)
    {
        int randNumber;
        Random gen2 = new Random();
        randNumber = numbers[gen2.nextInt(13)];
        return randNumber;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return numbers[number] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }
}
```

I have seen other people's examples on how to do this, but I tried to make my own version using random # generators within an array to randomly select a value and will assign said value to a suit / number. I cant seem to figure out what to put into the toString method though as I dont really know how to pull the results of the randomly generated cards from their arrays and convert them to string to say (Number) + " of " + (Suit)

any advice would be greatly appreciated. I was thinking it would be easier to just create an array of strings and pull the words out of them but I'm required to use int values and even then i wouldnt know how to pull out the array values/strings.

Comment: This `int[] numbers = new int[12];` is a local variable.

Comment: Could use two enums ([Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)). One for the suits, one for the numbers.

Comment: We havent learned about Enumeration, so not sure my professor would be up for accepting that. Ill look into it for sure though thank you. As for the int[] numbers = new int[12] being a local variable, I can't see whats wrong there I made it the way we were shown to create arrays :(

Comment: In that case, you could use a `switch(number)` statement or a string of `if-else if` statements.

Comment: Your arrays are not big enough... the size when initializing them is not zero based. [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: There is nothing wrong the numbers array but it won't be used anywhere with only the code we see here. It is only available within the Cards() constructor, which doesn't use it at all.

Comment: Sure there's a problem, he's missing 16 cards in his deck!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably implement two helper methods like so

```
private static String getSuit(int suit) 
{
  switch (suit) {
  case 0: return "Spades";
  case 1: return "Clubs";
  case 2: return "Diamonds";
  }
  return "Hearts";
}

private static String getCard(int card) 
{
  switch (card) {
  case 1: return "Ace";
  case 11: return "Jack";
  case 12: return "Queen";
  case 13: return "King"; // Assuming you want a 10...
  }
  return String.valueOf(card);
}
```

Then I would invoke them in the `toString()` method like so

```
public String toString()
{
    return getCard(numbers[number]) + " of " + getSuit(suits[suit]);
}
```